# Calculus Apostol Exercise 1.11 number 6

Tags: calculus, geometry

[image: Problem from Apostol Calculus Exercise 1.11 number 6]

I just don't know how to start with this problem, it seems obvious but I'm just stumped on how to start the proof. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to sketch this situation for a few different functions _f_?

Comment: No, but what do you mean by sketching for few different functions? from a to b?

Comment: Take some graph paper and graph functions in the interval $(a,b)$ , for example $(0,10)$ , and count the number of lattice points and compare with the formula given to you. This may help you find why the formula is true and show you a path towards its proof.

Comment: So does it suffice to show that the formula is true by showing that by counting arbitrary lattice points, it is also equal to the sum itself?

Answer (score 1):

We can help ourselves by drawing a picture to get a good idea of what is going on, then turn that intuition into something more rigorous.  The picture is as follows:

$\hskip1.5in$ [image]

In the picture, we can see (the filled in dots) the lattice points in the ordinate set of $f(x)$ (not including the $x$-axis since the question stipulates $S$ contains the points $0 < y \leq f(x)$).  At each integer between $a$ and $b$, we count the number of lattice points beneath $[f(x)]$, the greatest integer less than or equal to $f(x)$.  Then we need to turn this intuition from the picture into a proof:

*Proof.*  Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a \leq n < b$.  We know such an $n$ exists since $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a < b$.  Then, the number of lattice points in $S$ with first element $n$ is the number of integers $y$ such that $0 < y \leq f(n)$.  But, by definition, this is $[f(n)]$ (the greatest integer less than or equal to $f(n)$).  Summing over all integers $n, \ a \leq n \leq b$ we have,
$$ \text{# of lattice points in } S = \sum_{n=a}^b [ f(n) ]. \qquad \blacksquare$$

Comment: @ChristianBlatter How so?  If f is identically 0, then there are no such lattice points and the formula, in fact, gives 0.  Am I missing something?  The formula I arrive at agrees with the one requested in the problem statement.

Comment: I had missed the $0<y$. Sorry for the slip.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter No problem.  I was afraid I'd done something dumb in my first posted answer :)